# How do I convert date in normal format like "2017-03-03 09:46:22.103"?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Consider:

```
var myDate = $scope.today;
var previousDay = new Date(myDate);
previousDay.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
var date = previousDay; // 2017-03-04 09:46:22.103 +5.30 GMT
```

How do I get to only have "2017-03-03 09:46:22.103"?

Comment: AFAIK Angular doesn't have anything that allows you to format a date. You will probably want to use vanilla JS instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date.

Comment: Use this for further reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var requiredDateFormat = previousDay.toLocaleDateString() + " " + previousDay.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Comment: The format of *toLocaleDateString* is entirely implementation dependent and varies from host to host. There is no guarantee that the result will have the format in the OP. For me, Safari gives "3/5/2017", Firefox "05/03/2017".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().toJSON();`. It will return `"2017-03-04T04:55:50.786Z"`.

Comment: Thats what i dont want.

Comment: How can i get only date without time

Comment: Could you please post exact time stamp what you are looking for?